# mail function cause time out ! During mass mail.

Tags: php, sendmail

```
public function send_mail($event = '', $to=array(), $from=array(), $cc=array(), $bcc=array(), $reply_to = array(), $attachment=array(), $subject='', $body='', $is_html=true, $save_db=false, $immediate= true)
        {
            if(count($to)>0)
            {
                foreach($to as $key=>$value)
                {
                    if(!isset($value['name']))  
                        $value['name'] ='';

                    $this->AddAddress($value['address'], $value['name']);
                }
                $this->SetFrom($from['address'], $from['name']);    
                    }   
            else
                return false;   
        }
```

This function cause time out when more than 1000 records will be there!

Comment: PHP has an execution time limit to stop it running for ever and hogging the servers resources. Your code is taking long enough that the limit is reached. You can adjust the limit by setting `max_execution_time` in php.ini, but if you're on a hosting service you won't be able to change it.

Comment: Consider how many parameters a method has!

Comment: I have found several options here like ajax request which process "100" user-mail one time and like wise continue with its execution.also found php swift mailer library!

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the timeout of your mailingscript using

```
set_time_limit(seconds)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @lneentho : Thank you i am checking !

Comment: I hv used this ini_set("max_execution_time","300534");

So Execution time is increase but look like it is very slow !

can we do something on speed improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending out mass emails, put a sleep() in your loop. Some MTAs are configured to prevent flooding requests, and will hence stop your message delivery and may even impose penalties. You won't get a message mailed back to you, but the email server will generate a 4xx type error. I am not sure what your implementation is, but if you mail working off a queue, your mail() function is probably being directly to the mail system.